# A "non-mainstream" flag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flagging

I have noticed some "non-mainstream" (it may be rude to say crackpot) questions and answers recently such as:

**Questions**

- [Mass term in the Minkowski metric and an oscillation model in Lorentz group](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68508/mass-term-in-the-minkowski-metric-and-an-oscillation-model-in-lorentz-group) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdZRB.png))
- [Help me test and prove this theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68503/help-me-test-and-prove-this-theory) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUeqT.png))
- [Can we model gravitation as a repulsive force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26692/can-we-model-gravitation-as-a-repulsive-force)

**Answers**

- [What is the kinematics of a particle with complex mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16227/what-is-the-kinematics-of-a-particle-with-complex-mass/18678#18678) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11AHg.png))
- [Plausible explanations for 3 large space dimensions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/18645/plausible-explanations-for-3-local-space-dimensions/18666#18666) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0c1l.png))
- [What if we could give photons some mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17939/what-if-we-could-give-photons-some-mass/18676#18676) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zn1V.png))
- [What reasons are there to suspect string theory may be an incorrect theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1869/what-reasons-are-there-to-suspect-string-theory-may-be-an-incorrect-theory/16655#16655) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM90H.png)) (an instance of calling rather mainstream theory, string theory as fringe)
- [Models of neutrinos consistent with OPERA's results](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26906/models-of-neutrinos-consistent-with-operas-results/26909#26909) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F35j.png))

Currently, I am flagging these as "spam" because they are pretty much like advertisements but isn't it better to have a more specific flag associated with these, like "Non-mainstream"? Since "Spam" usually refers to answers like "me too! I would like to thank so and so website for leading me here" or "me too! So and so company can help you!" etc.

So, has this "Non-mainstream" -flag been proposed before? And what are your thoughts about it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yep, this has already been proposed [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4400/124), and it'll be implemented as soon as we have custom close reasons enabled. That might be happening later this week.

Incidentally, the spam flag should only be used for actual spam, by which I mean purely promotional posts with no relevance to the site. Things like

> CIALIS VIAGRA PRON xxx.example.com!!!!1!!

OK, I'm not very good at writing spam, but you get the idea. Posts about non-mainstream theories are not spam (in the sense of the flag) unless they link to some crackpot website promoting the theory and the purpose of the post is clearly nothing more than promotion of the site. Without that link, if non-mainstream posts are questions, flag them as off topic; if they are answers, downvote them.

Answer (score 9):

What demonstrates a complete rejection of an idea better:

- A unilateral decision by a moderator to delete a answer
- A hail of downvotes from the community placing the answer deep in negative score territory. (And with questions a hail of downvotes plus a community close.)

Further, given the number of times a week one moderator or another is accused of "doing it wrong" do you really want to encourage a culture in which we are aggressive about deleting content?

We also have a class of users who regularly offer correct answer to basic questions generating some rep for their account while at the same time promoting some--shall we say--"unusual" point of view on a more advanced topic. Downvoting rather than deleting their off-the-mainstream answers also serves to hold their rep down lest it fool a naive reader (*"Oh look that guy has a pretty good rep, he must be on to something"*).

Comment: To be honest, I don't think that last one works well. Due to the rep ratio of upvotes (+10) to downvotes (-2), users would have to "promote unusual points of view" five times more actively than they offer correct answers for this to kick in.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I've been watching a couple of selected users who I consider to be in this category. The steady downvoting of their unusual stuff is not going to prevent them from gaining (say) close privileges, but it has been holding them back on getting there. Way back. At some point I suppose we're going to have to issue long running suspensions for these users, but I've been trying to avoid it.

Comment: Holding them back by how much? How much rep have they won and how much have they lost? Is the latter as much as even 10% of the former? Unless it's above 20%(=2/10), I don't think the mechanism makes any real difference.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty My favorite example has received more downvotes than upvotes (so more than 20%, especially as many of this user's posts are questions not answers); is averaging substantially less than 1000 net rep per year and hasn't been gaining significant rep since an early rash of giving good answers to basic questions. It does make a difference.

Comment: OK, I guess it can make a difference. It still sounds like a pretty extreme situation for only a ~20% slowdown to me, though.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that non-mainstream physics is off-topic, but I would hope that moderators err on the side of inclusion; I went through all of the OP's links and learned a lot imagination/conjecture-wise, without being swayed into joining any shady physics cults ;)

Particularly, sourced rebuttals and elucidations present in answers on those topics do a lot to show me what is going on with some of the higher reaches of physics without climbing those crags myself. I'm not exactly sure how you would get the same result without questions of this kind to complete such a "Socratic method".

Say what you will about the wackiness of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75706/could-we-see-a-lower-dimension-within-our-universe/75787#75787) for example, but I learned a *lot* from the comments and the sole answer, and it was equally worth it to untangle what the OP was asking despite it being ill-formed, and, if the answerer is right, pointing at a non-mainstream theory (braneworld).

Answer (score 0):

Since Physics SE is about mainstream physics, you can flag such questions as off topic and it is best to clearly state in a comment on the question, that and maybe why you are sure it is not mainstream.

Concerning answers containing non mainstream physics, it is a bit more complicated since for answers there is no off topic flag reason. In this case I always chose the flag option to call for moderator attention and say in the text field that this answer promotes non mainstream physics and is therefore off topic. Leaving a comment below the answer does not hurt too.

Comment: Leaving a comment together with the flag is actually important to avoid too many such flags being wrongly declined by people who do not automatically see that the flagged post is about non mainstream physics and therefore not welcome here.

Comment: Just because an answer is wrong is not a reason you should be flagging it. That's what downvotes are for.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I am not talking about wrong answers and questions, but about nonconstructive trolling posts. Bei trolling I mean what is written in the wikipedia entry under the term internet trolling or flaming. I am momentarily not able to insert links.

Comment: I refuse to believe that things has gone so far by now, that nonconstructive trolling often by laypeople who have no clue what they are talking about, about legitimate mainstream physics, certain researchers, etc has to be tolerated here on physics SE. If it would be tolerated here, this would degrade physics SE to being no better than any unmoderated physics blogs, forums, or discussion below popular news article, where not knowledgable enough people often bunch up to spit and spat on legitimate physics topics and throwing stowns on physicists working in these fields, as soon as certain

Comment: Keywords are mentiond. I guess you should know what I am talking about, at least if you follow physics blogs from time to time...

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky and non mainstream physics has allways been off topic as far as I know. Or did I miss something and this has now changed too?

Comment: @Dilaton: Non mainstream physics is still off topic, and probably always will be. However, wrong physics is a different matter. About trolling:  No, the Wikipedia definition says `is a person who sows discord on the Internet by trying to start arguments and upset people`. We don't try to guess a person's intentions when they post non mainstream stuff. And a layperson posting wrong stuff is NOT a troll; they are working in good faith.

Comment: If someone is saying wrong things about mainstream physics; that is not non-mainstream by the definition used here. If I say that "the stress energy tensor in general relativity is the metric tensor plus the kronecker delta", that is wrong, but not non-mainstream (as it is about GR). If I post "GR is wrong, use <theory> instead", or "mass and length are equivalent", that is non mainstream.

Comment: @Manishearth the definition of trolling says it is come here to **upset** people, instead of getting or delivering correct information. You really say it is ok for people to come here with the only purpose to annoy and upset physicists?

Comment: @Dilaton: Yes, that's the definition of trolling. How do you know the intentions of the poster? Basically, trolling implies an understanding of the poster's intentions. We really can't just assume that. On the other hand, N-M physics is something that can be _objectively_ determined by looking at the post -- no need to research the user. It's not OK for people to do that. But having assumptions about a user sneak into policy -- that's not good either. I'm just against the usage of the terminology "trolling".

Comment: You seem not to understand what I mean, I dont mean posting wrong things or misunderstand things, but upseting physicists by **attacking** them or their work, way of thinking, etc in an **agressive** manner. Example of such trolling about mainstream physics as I often observe it is for example posting answers and questions here with the corresponding tags that are nothing but opionated hate speach about the topic of people wirking on it.

Comment: @Dilaton: Attacking a physicist is a personal attack and is deleted for that reason. Attacking their work usually is non-mainstream physics. If, however, a physicist's work is disputed in mainstream physics, saying that "X is wrong because reasons" is OK. Aggressiveness, again, can have problems and can be deleted for being offensive.

Comment: Basically, "trolling is not allowed here" is not something that can be objectively implemented in policy, because it assumes knowledge of the poster's intentions. Most cases of trolling get deleted for other reasons.

Comment: For example when a post says GR is compleze bullshit, perticle physicsbis nothing but a wast of money, people who believe in the higgs are complete idiots who delude the public to secure the jobs, quantum gravity is nothing but pseodo science and should not be allowed, a particular group of well known physicists are pseodo scientists and their work is rubbish, ect, the bad intention of the poster of such things is plain obvious.

Comment: @Dilaton: "GR is complete BS" is NM Physics. So are the rest of the reasons. There's a reason we have a rule against NM physics.

Comment: If the physicists here flag such posts, saying this is insulting or not.constructive, or comments saying that the post is nothing but a nonconstructive attacking insult of correct physics or physicists working on the topic, this should be taken seriosly. The bad thing is, that it sometimes even happens, that such **trolling** posts get even ** upvoted**, which gives the impression that Physics SE endorses and even encourages such **disruptive** behavior of people who are, clearly obvious to everybody, not here to learn and enjoy physics.

Comment: @Dilaton: The flags are taken seriously if it is indeed the case that the post is NC. Please give an example of the case you talk about. If you're talking about the "String Theory is not testable" answer, while that may not answer the question, it's not trolling in itself. That view is held by many physicists and isn't an attack.

Comment: On the other hand, "String theory is complete BS and a total waste of time", _is_ an attack, and can be deleted as such.

Comment: You may dislike expressions like trolling and flaming, but these are correct technical terms applied by social scientists who investigate the behavior of individuals and groups in the internet  or even in the real world too, if you read the whole wikipedia entries about trolling and flaming. And wikipedia says too that this kind of disruptive behavior is not harmless, if it persists and is not dealt with. And indeed, on Prof.  Strasslers physics.blog it is no longer possible to discuss the physics of supersymmetry for people interested in the physics of this concept, because as soon as the

Comment: Term supersymmetry is mentioned, the site gets full of aggresssive comments saying such things like people who believe in supersymmetry are pseudoscientists etc, searches for effects at the LHC are nothing but a waste of money etc etc... It would be really too bad, if such things start here too, as soon as somebody posts a question about certain topis.

Comment: @Manishearh the ST is not testable (one has to discern between directbat the planck scale evidence and hints at our present day experimental scale) is simply wrong and should therefore not end up with a positive net score. I know that many laypeople and even physicists who are not knowledgable (working on this particular topic) enough beleave this claim because it is often enough kicked around in the media, popular literature, etc to make reports about physics more exciting... But I disagree that this claim is promoted to be correct on physics SE too. This is an example that the voting system

Comment: Gets broken too often.

Comment: @dilaton I don't dislike those expressions. However, they should not be part of a flag reason or whatever, when (a) current flag reasons cover their use cases (b) We cannot assume the user's intentions. Again, _aggressive_ comments will be deleted because they are aggressive. Re:ST-testability: Wrong, but not trolling. And I have talked with many _physicists_ who feel that for ST to be tested to an appreciable extent, ultra-huge colliders will be required; which is why they're not that interested in it. And they don't mean it as an attack,

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that what you think is correct may not necessarily be true.  Especially in controversial matters like this. This is exactly why mods do not deal with the correctness of a post. We do not presume to know what physics is correct.

Comment: I reaally don't see the point of continuing this discussion. The ST thing was iirc adequately discussed on meta :/

Comment: @Manishearth in physics it can exactly be determined what is correct and what is not, if you dont see this you dont inderstand some quite fundamental properties of physics or the natural sciences generally. And saying that ST is not testable in principle and neglecting the difference between **direct** planck scale tests and **indirect** accessible lower energy hints is an attack too. Claiming that ST is not testable would mean that it is not not physics, which would be an unjustified degradation.  I know that too many physicist who dont work on ST and therefore dont understand it well

Comment: Enough promote this unjustified negative and sometimes even attacking attitude. But this does not make it right. Agreed that it is better to stop here, because you obviously will never understand what I am saying so further discussions are not constructive ... :-/

Comment: @dilaton uh, no it can't. The scientific method works, but for that you need irrefutable experimental evidence. And even then you can only be sure to a certain level of accuracy.  Also, the claim isn't that ST isn't testable, it's that ST isn't practically testable to a high level of accuracy (i.e. to the extent that GR has been tested) in the near future. Yes, there have been tests. However, if those tests are enough to conclusively say that "String Theory is correct" -- that's a subjective matter that people disagree on. And I respect their opinions on that.

Comment: @dilaton I understand what you're saying. I'm saying that different people (not cranks, well respected people) have different opinions on how much evidence is required to prove ST. Many people feel that only once the galaxy-size accelerator experiments are done, ST will be proved. Phy.SE doesn't take a stance on this, so it will permit all reasonably-stated views on the matter.

Comment: Again, while you feel it is unjustified and attacking, that may not be the view of a large portion of the physics community. Please understand that. We take no sides on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how non-mainstream is the same as crackpot-ism. If everyone keeps repeating mainstream teachings it's just religion. Were Galileo's views main-stream? Now, I know this isn't a place for publishing research. But especially considering the various equally valid interpretations of quantum mechanics: There seems to be a strong bias towards the Kopenhagen interpretation on stackexchange.

Majority vote or having read something in a main-stream book has nothing to do with scientific evidence.

The result of this anti-non-mainstream-policy is that for example renowned physicists like Nobel laureate 't Hooft giving scientific good answers are downvoted simply because what he is talking about is relatively new and not yet mainstream. (Not that it should matter who the answerer is. It just goes to show that the assumption that all non-mainstream posts are basically from 10 year old know-it-alls, is wrong.)

Mainstream orthodoxy and dogmatism have always stood in the way of scientific progress!

Why not simply a non-mainstream tag instead of a non-mainstream flag?

Comment: I suspect you're interpreting the non-mainstream closure reason as broader than it is used in practice, and in my experience the kinds of nonmainstreamness you're describing don't get closed. There is [at present](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297750) no in-system way to audit this but [this google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22We+deal+with+mainstream+physics+here%22+site%3Aphysics.stackexchange.com) returns the non-deleted closed questions under that reason.

Comment: Do have a poke around that list; if you do find the kind of questions you're describing ─ good science done honestly but a bit off the beaten track, while keeping in mind that [we're not a venue for peer review](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7516) ─ then that would be problematic, and I would encourage you to post such a list as a separate thread on this meta. However, I think you'll mostly be half horrified at the kind of stuff that gets posted, with the other half agreeing that it needed to be closed.

Comment: (Similarly, it may not have been obvious as to the kinds of questions and answers OP was referring to; see the edited question for publicly-accessible screenshots of the kinds of post under discussion in this specific thread.)