# Chat session to discuss and possibly finalize close reasons

Tags: discussion, status-completed, vote-to-close, close-reasons

We have a bunch of proposed close reasons [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4398/what-will-our-list-of-close-reasons-look-like), and there recently have been a few more good ones brought up there (Like Chris' alternative homework close reason or tpg's "engineering" close reason).

We need to have some consensus for these, so we'll hold an extra chat session next Tuesday at 16:00UTC (same timing as our regular biweekly chat session, though we don't have that next week).

The agenda of the event is to discuss close reasons, and settle on a final set of three close reasons and their wording.

If the timings are inconvenient, lease let me know. I'm open to changing it if enough people ask for it.

It's OK if you have some points to make but won't be able to make it into the room. You can post those points on the [close reasons thread](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4398/what-will-our-list-of-close-reasons-look-like), and we'll try to include that in our assessment.

You can register for the discussion [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/71/the-h-bar?tab=schedule) (it also lists what time it will at in your timezone)

### Update

Chat session over: [Part 1](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/conversation/close-reason-discussion-part-1), [Part 2](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/conversation/close-reason-discussion-part-2).

We have elected to remove the Math close reason, as we nw have a migration path to Math.

The three proposed close reasons are below. If you would like to improve them or feel that they are counterproductive, please comment below them. (I suggest you check the bookmarked sub-discussion before commenting, the point may have been brought up)

If the majority of the community feels that they are OK, these will probably be locked in tomorrow-ish

Comment: Comment 13. aug 2014: Here we are only discuss _off-topic_ closing reasons, which the Phys.SE community can decide themselves. To those readers who wonder where all the other close-reasons are (i.e. _duplicate of, unclear what you're asking, too broad, primarily opinion-based_), these are common to all SE sites, and the Phys.SE community cannot change those.

Answer (score 5):

Reason #1: Homework

[Bookmarked chat converation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/conversation/homework-close-reason-discussion)

> Homework-like questions should **ask about a specific physics concept** and **show some effort** to work through the problem. We want our questions to be useful to the broader community, and to future users. See [our meta site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) for more guidance on how to edit your question to make it better.

Answer (score 5):

Reason #2: Non-mainstream physics

[Bookmarked chat conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/conversation/non-mainstream-physics-close-reason-discussion)

> We deal with **mainstream physics** here. Questions about the general correctness of unpublished personal theories are off topic, although specific questions evaluating new theories in the context of established science are usually allowed. For more information, see [Is non mainstream physics appropriate for this site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4539/7433).

Answer (score 4):

Reason #3: Engineering

[Bookmarked chat conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/conversation/engineering-close-reason-discussion)

> This question appears to be about **engineering**, which is the application of scientific knowledge to construct a solution to solve a specific problem. As such, it is off topic for this site, which deals with the **science**, whether theoretical or experimental, of how the natural world works. For more information, see [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4536/7433).

[Meta post, under construction](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/are-engineering-questions-appropriate-for-this-site)

Comment: Hmm one minor suggestion comes to mind: remove the 6th-to-last word, "studying" - otherwise we are describing philosophy of physics, aren't we?

Comment: @ChrisWhite Yes, that makes sense. Removed. :)