# How about common edit summaries and common comments?

Tags: feature-request, editing, comments, retagging

On Wiki Pedia, for example, when you make an edit (to the source) , there is a box called "Common edit summaries."

[image: Common Edit Summaries]

And also minor edit summaries.

[image: Common Minor Edit Summaries]

So that many common edits can be given quick summaries, to save time.

It's not that important at Wiki (since edit summaries aren't compulsoury), but I guess it would be ***very useful here at Physics.SE***.  Not just for edits, but for comments, also. For example, I find that I'm often repeating the same comment:

"[Homework Policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)."

"[Please show more effort while asking homework questions. Don't expect anyone to do your work for you.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange)."

"[Non-mainstream questions are not allowed here.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site)."

"[Does your "theory" have any mathematics? What does it predict? What can I calculate with it? Please don't promote your own non-mainstream ideas here.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site)."

"+1 Nice question!"

"+1 Nice answer!"

"Huh? This is very unclear?! What are you even talking about?" . 
  / . .

Which means coming to meta ($ \geq $ 1 min waiting time), searching for [faq] ($ \geq 30 $ seconds waiting time), then clicking ($ \geq 30 $ seconds waiting time),  Linking to it and parsing the link and adding the text ($ \geq 1 $ minute typing time), which amounts to 4 minutes. Well, that's not that long, but this same process is repeated for multiple, multiple posts. So,

> ***Question 1.*** Could there be a feature "Common coments".

Now, for the edits. Till recently,  I would just write something like, because its quick:

"SNJDSJDWIEE21!!!!S';DSDJSJDJUQJIDUFDNS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!11111111111111111........    "

Or something like that. Recently, for some reason, I got bored of typing nonsense, so I just type.

"Added homework tag."

"Added popular-science tag."

"Corrected LaTeX."

"Don't use big-list tag."

"It seems as if the homework tag applies even if it isn't real homework." (Yup, that's copied from Qmechanic.)

"Removed irrelevant tags."

"Removed irrelevant tag."

"Removed irrelevant reference-request tag."

"Removed irrelevant string-theory tag. This is a kinematics question."

"Removed irrelevant string theory tag."

"Removed irrelevant research-level tag."

"Removed irrelevant Mathematical Physics tag."

"Added LaTeX."

"Removed unnecessary Controversial statements."

"Fixed grammar."

And such things. It is quite monotonous to repeatedly write this, so

> ***Question 2:*** Could the same feature as requested in Q1 be applied to Edit Summaries too? (It would be even better if the system would detect the tags which have been changed, like if I add a pop-sci tag, for e.g., then it has in the common edit summaries, "Added Popular-Science tag.", but perhaps that's just too much.)    .
>    .

*Edit:* This is useful only to < 2k reputation users.

Thanks. !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For "common comments", you can use [this userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se).

I never really felt the need for edit summaries when I was a <2k user. Wikipedia has a *much* larger need as you have a few thousand edits in a question history and finding a particular edit can be annoying. (FWIW the "common edit summaries" feature wasn't there a year ago). Over here, the purpose of the summary is to explain to the reviewer what you are doing. In this case, it is better to be verbose.

It would be nice to have, but, again, I don't see much of a need.

I like the proposal for automatically adding a tag edit summary for the case of tag-only edits. Till recently, users with 5k rep could edit tags without approval.

Comment: 5k? You mean 500, right? I checked that userscript, trying to add it... I guess I'll use firefox instead...

Comment: @Dimension10 No, at 500. You get a separate retag option that lets you change tags without approval. For help installing, see http://stackapps.com/tags/script/info

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I don't need to use firefox to  use it! .