# Missing comments

Tags: discussion

I remember posting some comments under [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/192567/27367), but they aren't there now (in particular there was a comment about question edit and another that lead to [this reply](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/192561/how-does-the-heat-death-looks-like-from-inside-the-system#comment410044_192567)).

I'm quite sure I didn't delete them myself, there were a few of them and they are all gone. Hence, I suspect moderator action. As I am new to the physics.SE community I would like to ask why these comments were removed, or more importantly why there was no note left. I tried searching help center and meta for some info or policies, but to no avail. I did find that "moderators reserve right to delete comments without notice" and I'm aware of general SE policy that "comments are ephemeral in nature", but removing several comments from a new member without any note just seems not right (I participate a bit in other SE communities being "trusted user" in two and I don't remember any such thing happening).

Could somebody let me know what happened? Is this a standard thing here? Is there any community norm help page so that I can read it and avoid at least a part of stepping on your toes?

Comment: Well you quote two relevant truths: comments are not permanent & can deleted at any time. Not sure what more you're looking for than that.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I deleted three comments because they seemed to represent a completed exchange starting with suggestions to improve the post, an indication that the improvements had been made and an acknowledgement from the person making the suggestion.

Mission accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

*[dmckee gave a very succinct answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6905/46399), but perhaps he was short on time or likewise, so that answer is not self contained. I am including the part that he left out.*

See [this guide-post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6374/which-flag-do-i-use-for-an-inappropriate-post) regarding flagging.

One of the valid comment flags is:

> *Obsolete*
>
> The "obsolete" flag is for comments that have served their purpose or outlived their usefulness, such as
>
> - suggestions for changes which have been incorporated into the post, or which the poster has explicitly declined to make
> - requests for clarification which have been answered, and their answers
> - back-and-forth discussions which are no longer active
> - responses to comments which have been deleted
> - pretty much any comment older than a week or so

Reading dmckee's answer in this light,

> I deleted three comments because they seemed to represent a completed exchange starting with suggestions to improve the post, an indication that the improvements had been made and an acknowledgement from the person making the suggestion.

... which means the reason above the bullets directly applies here, and coupled with the ephemeral nature of the comments, they could be deleted as normal cleanup on this site.

Hence, he says:

> Mission accomplished.

Comment: Please note that I am not necessarily implying that the comments got flagged for deletion - I guess so, but I don't know. I'm just saying that they qualified for deletion.