# Should there be a way to flag comments

Tags: discussion, comments

When experienced users make the first comment on a "bad" question, they are often condescending. This is fair enough, if the question is bad. However, this discourages other, less experienced users with less reputation, from attempting to answer the question. Particularly if the question is an interesting one and the "experienced user" who initially commented, has perhaps misunderstood it. The example I use is here

[Does a gun exert enough gravity on the bullet it fired to stop it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206440/does-a-gun-exert-enough-gravity-on-the-bullet-it-fired-to-stop-it)

Regardless of anyone's opinion on the example mentioned, my question is whether there should be some process for flagging unnecessarily condescending and useless comments, particularly from experienced contributors, which may discourage other users from answering, or encourage less experienced users to "jump on the bandwagon" simply because of the reputation of the comment writer.

Comment: If the comment is wrong, then flag it, that's it. This is not at all related to reputaion or rep numbers. Just neglect the comment otherwise. It is as simple as that. I couldn't conceive what the bone of contention is:/

Comment: @user36790 one clarification to that: if a comment is factually incorrect, that itself doesn't justify flagging it. It may still be flaggable for other reasons.

Comment: @DavidZ: I do agree, sir; `don't be rude, be nice` & all that....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a process: click the flag that shows up when you **hover over the left side of a comment**, and flag the comment.

[image: screenshot of a comment with the flag visible]

(there's nothing wrong with this particular comment except that it's old)

[This meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6375/124) lists the different kinds of comment flags and what they should be used for.

Bear in mind that if a question is bad, those high-reputation users may be *intentionally* trying to discourage people from answering it. Of course, the proper way to do that is by voting to close, but sometimes a comment gives a little extra boost to that effort before the question does get closed.