# The problem with spam flags

Tags: support, flagging, spam

I have flagged quite a few posts and answers, 2 of which were spam flags and both were declined.  Why?  Isn't spam anything redundant and lengthy?  For instance, if a person's answer is "hieeeeeeeeeeeeeeefiehfihfiehihefhehfie" some random letters like this, is this spam?

Comment: [Spamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamming) - *Electronic spamming is the use of electronic messaging systems to send an unsolicited message (spam), **especially advertising***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not spam.

On StackExchange, only posts that explicity advertise a specific website, program or product are considered spam. [Gibberish should be flagged as either "not an answer" or "rude or abusive"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/280545).

Comment: I meant what should gibberish questions be flagged as.  Sorry for misunderstanding

Comment: @XcoderX I explicitly said what gibberish posts should be flagged as. I don't understand your question.

Comment: You can neither flag it as not an answer, Nor rude or abusive, since it is a question

Comment: @XcoderX You can certainly flag questions as "rude or abusive". Please be more specific about the problems you encounter or I will stop responding to you.

Comment: Okay @ACuriousMind .  I will keep that in mind.  So such gibberish will be ‘abusive’, since you can’t say that it is ‘rude’.

Comment: @XcoderX I'm puzzled by your response. The last sentence of my answer literally says that gibberish can be flagged as "rude or abusive". How did you deduce that it cannot be flagged as 'rude'?

Comment: I would add "very low quality" to the list of flag options. That's my flag of choice for such content. See also [this question about flags](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6374/which-flag-do-i-use-for-an-inappropriate-post)

Comment: @DavidZ [We've always had slightly different opinions on what the VLQ flag ist for](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8952/50583) ;)

Comment: @XcoderX I literally have no idea what you are talking about. I said in my answer that gibberish can be flaggedas *either* "not an answer" *or* "rude or abusive", and yet your last three comments imply that you somehow concluded from this that gibberish isn't rude. I would be very interested to learn how you got from by statement that "you may flag gibberish as rude or abusive" to the idea that "gibbersih isn't rude". That doesn't follow from anything that was written, at all.

Comment: Let me clarify.  I know what to flag a gibberish post as now.  However, I would like to know why is there no flag for abusive only.  I think gibberish is abusive, not rude though

Comment: @XcoderX Please direct questions about the types of available flags at [meta.SE] instead of physics.SE, since this concerns all sites equally.

Comment: "_I think gibberish is abusive, not rude though_" That's why the flag is "Rude **or** abusive".