# Spam flag on nonsense garbage declined

Tags: discussion, support, flagging, spam

Sorry for raising this up weeks later, because I just checked my flag logs today.

My spam flag on [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/433026) was

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

(Note: Post is already deleted and user nuked)

According to [metasmoke](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/post/138185), the post content was:

> QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890

As per [this FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035), *rude or abusive* flags are appropriate on this kind of garbage. Quoting below:

> #### What makes something rude or abusive and when should I flag it?
>
> ...
>
> *Abuse of the system or community* is everything that is created with the intention to harm them. This includes posts that contain *no useful content at all* – i.e. gibberish posts along the lines of:
>
> > asyuv;laergap897wertp[98 gb;vp98a34

Furthermore, as [stated by Shog9](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/conversation/shogs-point-on-flagging-gibberish), it's fine to use either kind of red flags for this:

> ... and the same applies to Spam and Rude/Offensive ([source](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/26704952#26704952))

(it is also [supported by a previous CM, Pops](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35745740#35745740))

There's also [another consensus on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345333) that mixing spam flags and R/A flags are OK, since they're both high-priority red flags.

Synthesizing all references presented above, I think my spam flag is appropriate on that answer, so why is it declined?

I cast a spam flag instead of a R/A flag because it is more convenient with Tampermonkey userscripts that I have installed.

---

P.S. There was [a similar complaint](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3672) by someone else about a similar issue over on Drupal Answers.

Comment: I've received the rejected flag message: " The "spam" flag is mostly intended for *commercial* spam" when I used a spam flag on gibberish. Perhaps it would have been better if you had gotten that message since it is more descriptive.

Answer (score 11):

Note that "spam" is notably *missing* from the list of flags (VLQ, rude or abusive, not an answer) Shog9 lists in the answer you quote. The spam flag description reads:

> Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation.

A gibberish post does not, by any reasonable interpretation, qualify as promoting anything, therefore your flag was declined. Since spam flags feed an automated spam defense mechanics in a way that the other flags don't, please reserve the usage of the spam flag to actual promotional spam.

Comment: I swear there's another piece of word from Shog saying that spam flags are appropriate. Wait for me to find that out. I'll be back.

Comment: Furthermore, spam flags and R/A flags **both** feed into SE's SpamRam, the only differences are about review auditing and automatic question protecting, which is not the case on this site.

Comment: OK, what about [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345333)?

Comment: As I read [Shog9's answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234032/why-dont-we-treat-rubbish-the-same-as-spam/234035#234035) (no longer linked in the question here), it appears to me that Shog9 intended to include spam flags as valid, but more as an afterthought (emphasis mine): "It's VLQ, it's abuse, it's Not An Answer, *heck it might even be a spammer*, testing the waters... There's no metric you can apply that'll narrow that down…" So, while it's clearly not his preferred flag (he says he's partial to R/A), it does appear to me that he intended to include spam flags as a valid flag type.

Comment: DavidZ once [mentioned in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45670145#45670145) that VLQ applies to (what I classify as) keyboard slams and gibberish.

Comment: Yeah, VLQ is precisely the kind of flag to use for this sort of content. Incidentally, [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6374/which-flag-do-i-use-for-an-inappropriate-post) is the place to look for guidance about how to use flags on _this_ site (although I need to update that since the flags have changed semi-recently)