# Why are many of my questions closed?

Tags: discussion, voting

Every time I ask a question on this site, the community deals with it in a strange way, such as closing it, marking it as a duplicate, deleting it, or voting down.

I don't know that this only happens to me or happened to all.

All this feels as if someone tells you to shut up and ask only mainstream physics questions, or whatever. I do not want to change anything here
but I have two questions about this:

- Is it polite to manage site like this?! Physicists are people.
- Is the quality of the questions raised by this policy? As far as I can see the quality of questions on this site is very low, and has dropped every year.

Comment: Are you able to provide a specific example

Comment: You have [15+ upvoted, answered questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A26665+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1+score%3A1+closed%3Ano). "Every" is a strong word.

Comment: I think this question is reasonably phrased, but frankly, the title is not doing the question any favours - I'm downvoting specifically because of that. Maybe you can choose a title that actually reflects the question as posed - or provide evidence of this 'conspiracy' the title talks about?

Comment: It is “Stack Exchange”, not “stackexchange” (see the last section of [http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance), "Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name"). Please edit the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I edited for grammar/readability and changed the title to more accurately reflect the question (I may again change the title, as it still isn't very good).

Comment: @heather I would say changing the title is too substantial of an edit. The user clearly feels slighted by a conspiracy and that ultimately is the core of the discussion they want to start. I think the approach Emilio took is the right one - suggest a change, but ultimately their whole point hinges on conspiracy. That said, I'm not going to roll back the edit.

Comment: @tpg2114 good to know for future reference - thanks.

Comment: "*All this feels as if someone tells you to shut up and ask only mainstream physics questions, or whatever.*" This community has decided to [put non-mainstream physics questions as off-topic](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site/4539#4539), so you have to abide the policy if you want to use this site. Also, I hope you realize that this is a Q&A site, not an open discussion forum.

Answer (score 14):

Without specific instances, it is hard to say. But I have looked through your list of questions available to me (you may have deleted more, but I can't see those), I challenge your assertions.

- Of 27 questions you have asked, 7 have been marked as duplicate or off-topic.
- 3 of these questions were asked in 2014.
- For what it's worth, I agree with the close reasons on all of them, except maybe one, but I don't know enough in the area to be comfortable distinguishing between the marked duplicate and the edited question as posed.
- Only 5 *total* questions have a net negative score, all of which are at -1. Meanwhile, your most positive question is at +35.

So, given all that, I see very little to substantiate claims of being picked on or conspired against. I also don't see anything to indicate somebody was rude to you, unless you perceive close messages as rude.

But, to answer your two questions -- yes, this is a polite way to run the site because it doesn't appear anybody was untoward or rude. And yes, this does keep the quality of the questions up, but since there's no objective metric to define that, the discussion in that area will just devolve to personal opinions and it's not a fruitful direction to venture.

Comment: There *are* some deleted questions as well. Of the questions asked so far in 2017, two were self-deleted after being closed, one was [automatically reaped](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) after having been closed for a month, and one was removed based on [flags](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: @tpg2114
What if I am not convinced? 
I think  This a process of
vote down -> Censorship
vote down-> Censorship

How could I ever know that community vote down?

Comment: Maybe some people conspired together against Specific users for unknown political reasons

Comment: @Achmed Unfortunately, you made some pretty bold claims with no substantiation, so the onus is on you to convince us, not the other way around. I'm not convinced of your argument and outlined the data points that lead me to that conclusion. I recommend, if you really do feel slighted, to outline your points with data points so we are all on the same page. But if all you have is a hunch with no support, the only advice I can give you is to trust the system works. Or don't, nobody is forcing you to participate.

Comment: @rob I suspected as much. It doesn't really change my conclusions though. I'll update my answer a bit to reflect that when I get a few minutes. I wasn't going to chime in, but I saw you guys have had your hands... full... recently and thought I should help out where I could!

Comment: @tpg2114
I'm not convinced of your argument and outlined the data points that lead me to that conclusion.

that is because you are You are sitting there and I sit here
From where I'm sitting, everything looks like a full-blown conspiracy

Comment: @tpg2114
> nobody is forcing you to participate

that is true
but
I think it should be mentioned in this web site that entry of non-EU and non-US nationals are forbidden

Comment: @Achmed Well, then there's frankly nothing anybody can do to help you out of that one. If you can logically lay out evidence to support your conclusions that's one thing. But if not, then there's not much anybody can do. I don't see any trends in what I have access to that would support it. So, my advice is to either shake it off and keep contributing, or don't. But it sounds like further discussion is just going to go in circles as I doubt, should there be a real conspiracy, that the perpetrators are going to post an answer owning up to it.

Comment: @Achmed Uh, again, can you provide any context at all for that assertion? Unless there is something that went massively wrong in the 4 questions rob mentioned, there is 100% no way to reach that conclusion. Until you said otherwise, I had no idea you weren't US or EU.

Comment: @tpg2114
in the site that everythings gets vote down logic is dead!

Comment: @Achmed Okay, well, when you're ready to take off the tin foil and decide to approach this logically with evidence, I'll be happy to rejoin the conversation. Until then, I'm done.

Comment: @Achmed This site is essentially run by it's active members.  To try and say there is some higher level conspiracy going on just seems mad to me.  I act independently; as it seems like the other active members do as well.  Heck, I see more active community members disagree quite often.  The important part to remember is that the community decides what they want here.  If the community on average doesn't think it's a good question; I don't see what you could do about it.  No one is forcing you to use this site; and no one is forcing others to vote in particular ways.

Comment: @Achmed I also find it strange you say "entry of non-EU and non-US nationals are forbidden".  I don't think I've ever seen any such rule enforced.  Are you perhaps confused because very poorly worded questions get downvoted?  That is nothing to do with the nationality of the person asking; but more with the communities ability to understand the intent of what was asked.  If it's not clear what you ask, it's not clear how to answer it; therefore people generally regard it as a poor question.

Comment: @Achmed *"entry of non-EU and non-US nationals are forbidden"* i think your confusing SE's general moderation practice of removing non-english questions and answers with xenophobia. with the exception to some SO, Language and Culture Sites SE is primarily an english site with mist of the community understanding english. when you post in another language this then needs to be translated to english so that other users can attempt to understand it which takes time away from moderation unless we just run it through a machine translation which isn't 100% accurate

Comment: (cont.) also i'm Australian born and living in Australia. Australia isn't in the EU and isn't the US. i am not forbidden to enter any site on SE thus my very being here disproves that Non-EU and Non-US nationals are forbidden on the site