# Why doesn't one get points for an upvoted question on PhysicsMeta?

Tags: support

Why does one get no 5 points for an upvoted question in this place? I ask this because I asked [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10316/is-there-a-stackexchange-place-where-i-can-ask-questions-about-non-mainstream-ph) question, for which I got 3 upvotes, but no +15 points. Poor me!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because there's a fundamental difference between the main site and meta.

On the main site, people are voting based on how good/correct an answer is, which should be tied to your reputation - if you write really good, correct answers about physics, you should have a high reputation because you (presumably) get upvotes on those awesome answers. The opposite should also be true there.

On meta, people are voting based purely on opinion. On the main site, we *know* when there's an error in the answer - if someone says $F =m^2 a$, that's just wrong, no ifs, ands, or buts about it. On the other hand, on meta, someone could say that homework questions should be allowed, and another say they shouldn't be, and neither would be categorically right or wrong - we can look at their arguments for each viewpoint and think about who makes the better argument, and vote based on that, but in the end it comes down to opinion.

Just because you have controversial or well-respected opinions should not affect your reputation, because it has nothing to do with the actual topic of the site and there isn't really a "right" answer on meta.

Also, a quick note from [the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/22/new-per-site-metas/) (see point #5):

> **Voting up or down does not affect reputation.** You are now free to vote purely based on post content, without worrying about how your vote might positively or negatively affect someone’s reputation score.

Comment: I was thinking of what an answer to this question would look like, and it was basically this.  Can you imagine if it counted meta votes here?  It would literally be a gauge of who has "better" opinions.  Quite a funny concept.

Comment: I wouldn't say all meta votes are purely based on opinion. There's a spectrum, with some questions looking for opinions as answers while others have correct and incorrect answers (e.g. asking about established policies, history of the site, etc.), and plenty that are somewhere in the middle.

Comment: @DavidZ, sure; on the other hand, opinionated votes are the reason that reputation attention attached to them would be a little weird, so that's why I gave that most of my focus.

Answer (score -2):

All upvotes and downvotes on META do not contribute to changes in reputation

Comment: Seems to me OP recognizes this fact and wants to know *why* this is the case.