# The mainstream-physics close reason has a link to meta with the user ID of a moderator. Can it be removed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, close-reasons, non-mainstream-physics, links

Basically, what it says on the tin. The mainstream-physics closure dialog, which is accessible on the closure dialog as well as on closed questions ([example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/411503/)), contains a link to the [mainstream-physics site policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538) which contains the user ID of one of the elected site moderators, i.e. the same link that comes from [the 'share' button](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/) on that meta thread.

> [image]

Now, I don't think it's the end of the world, beyond [a somewhat-shady Announcer badge](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/announcer?userid=7433), but now that we know it's there, wouldn't it be better to remove that numerical tagline? Can this be done on a relatively painless fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to change the text of an existing close reason. We'd have to create a whole new one, presumably with the same text except for the link URL. Personally, I don't think it's worth the trouble, although you're right that it would be best not to have a user ID in the URL.

If we ever decide that the text of the close reason is somehow inadequate or invalid and we want to make a significant change to it, that would justify abandoning the close reason in favor of a new one. At that point we should definitely make sure not to attach any user IDs to the URL.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected as much; if nothing else, there's certainly a record-keeping concern here. Arguably there's a bit of wiggle room in that the change is minor (maybe worth bringing up with the team?) but it's not a huge deal either.

Comment: Sure, we can check with the team. I wouldn't expect much chance of a positive response though.

Comment: I changed it, @Emilio. Manish's badges can remain though, as a monument to his evil genius.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks =). Out of curiosity, is this a new entry in the CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes table, or is it a 'ghost' edit?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Old closed questions have the updated link, which suggests a ghost edit.