# Why has this question been put on hold?

Tags: support, specific-question, close-reasons

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post: [What is wrong about the following reasoning concerning hypersphere cosmology?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/461176/)

I was wondering why it is put on hold. It is honestly not clear to me.

Answer (score 5):

Your post is currently on hold because it is incomprehensible what the reasoning is supposed to be.

Taking an analogy with the 2-sphere, you seem to be claiming that someone moving along the surface of the Earth between the two points moves a greater distance than the distance between the two points "we measure". But if we were truly creatures confined to the surface (like we would be in the case where three-dimensional space is a hypersphere), we would measure the distance *along the surface*, so there is no discrepancy.

Comment: This place seems to be crawling with [flatlanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland).

Comment: Just because you don't understand the subject doesn't mean the question is incomprehensible. Why not just let people answer that _do_ understand?

Comment: Is there something like a meta meta post?

Comment: @魔大农 No. [Non-mainstream physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4538/50583) is off-topic here. viXra does not qualify as a reputable source.

Comment: You mean non-dogmatic physics?

Comment: As it is clear that the community here is not to your standard it would be useful for all of you took your debate elsewhere.