# Fast successive upvotes and downvotes: Is critical thinking forbidden here?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, voting

There is recently an odd reaction to my questions/answers. I see when somebody dislikes any, it is straightforwardly downvoted $-$ probably by somebody else. Or, when I ask a challenging question, in many cases, it is soon voted to be closed with the excuse of off-topic or something, esp. when no one can represent a clear answer in a due time, whereas the question is clear and technical enough to be given full consideration. And much worse, some of my questions have been *removed* from the site rather than just being closed so that no one has any access to them. Why these questions are deleted? Who is responsible for this?

It is easy to vote to close a question/answer (including this question!); why is not it possible to vote to leave a question open at the same time? (To vote to reopen a closed question, remember that it is not easy to find a specific closed question.)

Do all these indicate a kind of  **mainstream dictatorship** in here?

All in all, I think there is a suspicion against my activities as a critical thinker in this site, and hence, I believe there are some people of the **community** who are determined to limit my activities and reduce my reputation.

Is critical thinking $-$ yet logical $-$ something forbidden for this website?! Is really any critical thinker or dissident scientist a GUILTY in the community's view or that of the majority regardless of how deep his thoughts/questions/answers are?

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand your question here.  Why would you think critical thinking is "forbidden" because you get fast upvotes and downvotes?  Just based on this question, perhaps some of the negative reactions are because it isn't always clear what you are trying to say.

Comment: What type of answer are you expecting here? Sometimes answers get down votes. You can't please everyone, but that doesn't mean the couple of down votes represents all users here. Fortunately, down votes don't take your reputation down as much as up votes raise it. Just post good quality answers. The up votes will make the down vote irrelevant.

Comment: Voting to close this question is another kind of discrimination too.

Comment: Can you at-least provide a list of questions which fulfil "whereas the question is clear" by you in this meta?

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry That's absurd.  As I mentioned in my previous comment, this question is _unclear_; so for that reason alone close votes would be fair, not discrimination (in the way you seem to be using it).  There are also some votes as primarily opinion based, which seems valid here.

Comment: The issue is that this is not a legitimate question about how the site works. You got some down votes, and instead of evaluating the quality of your answers you are deciding to just make some broad accusations that do not have any real evidence. If the entire community decided to down vote your answers then your reputation would definitely be at the minimum 1 point.

Comment: @More Anonymous Some of those dissenting questions have been "removed", rather than just closed, by the community.

Comment: To address your recent edit *It is easy to vote to close a question/answer (including this question!); why is not it possible to vote to leave a question open?* You actually can vote to reopen questions. And that adds it to the reopen queue for other users to vote on as well. Before a question is closed, choosing to not vote to close I would say counts as a "vote to stay open".

Comment: I don't think "mainstream dictatorship" is the right wording; but this site is for _mainstream physics_.  [See here for more information](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/is-non-mainstream-physics-appropriate-for-this-site/4539#4539)

Comment: @ Aaron Stevens You are right but finding a specific  closed question is not very easy.

Comment: @MohammadJavanshiry The question will but automatically put into the queue if it has substantial edits.  People don't have to search out questions to reopen them.  Closed questions that get improved get put in the queue, so users with the power to reopen can just check the queue and vote to reopen if they feel it is appropriate.

Comment: I was in the middle of writing an answer to this question when it was closed, so I've used my diamond-moderator superpowers to reopen it.  However, if the community closes it again, I won't interfere.

Comment: @rob Oh, whoops I closed it before noticing your comment or that it had been closed before. But I think it will be best to respect the community's decision here.

Comment: @DavidZ No complaint from me.

Answer (score 3):

> I see when somebody dislikes any, it is straightforwardly downvoted − probably by somebody else.

The diamond moderators have some tools to look at voting patterns, and it doesn't seem like there are any users who are specifically targeting you with up- or down-votes.  It's much more labor-intensive to look into the *timing* of votes, so I haven't done that, even though the timing of votes seems to be the main thrust of your question here.  However, I think that what you're seeing is that questions which have been updated recently are viewed by a large number of users while they are on the front page of the site.  As our community has developed, we've come to a pretty firm understanding of the kinds of posts that are and aren't received well, and vote accordingly.  This solidarity [can lead to an unpleasant pile-on effect](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/) for users who aren't comfortable with those norms.

> Or, when I ask a challenging question, in many cases, it is soon voted to be closed with the excuse of off-topic or something. ... And much worse, some of my questions have been *removed* from the site rather than just being closed so that no one has any access to them. Why these questions are deleted?

You've asked sixteen questions since September 1; only three of them have been closed, and only one of those this month.  That suggests to me that you are getting better at learning to use our system.

Of your three closed recent questions, two are deleted.  One you removed yourself, and the other was caught by the [roomba](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/roomba).  You can view lists of your recent posts which are deleted (but not of older questions which have been deleted recently) from the appropriate part of the activity page on your profile; [here's your questions link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/127415).  (If that's actually a moderator-only tool, sorry for misleading you.  Other users note that you should be able to view your *own* deleted recent questions from your *own* profile page, but you may get a "404 - denied" error if you try to view a list of someone else's deleted recent questions.)

> It is easy to vote to close a question/answer (including this question!); why is not it possible to vote to leave a question open at the same time?

It's possible to vote "Leave Open" in the [review queue](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review), and enough such votes remove a post from the queue. There's more documentation in the [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help).

> Is critical thinking − yet logical − something forbidden for this website?

Critical thinking is absolutely welcome in our community.  However, as one of my favorite mentors likes to say, nothing resembles a new effect quite so much as a mistake.  We're not equipped to help all comers decide whether their [non-mainstream ideas](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/) are actual discoveries, for a variety of reasons, so we tend to close those types of questions unless they are exceptionally well-written and compelling.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. I hope everything goes well from now on!

Comment: I love the “nothing resembles a new effect quite so much as a mistake.”  Priceless.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I was going to say the same.  I'm going to try to have to remember that one.