# Site recommendation - basic question concerning Ohm's law

Tags: discussion, scope, resource-recommendation

Taking in to account the majority of posts and comments concerning very basic (not homework) questions here: [What can be done about the (current) ongoing flood of homework and very basic questions overwhelming our site?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4337/287083).

Can someone suggest where I might get some clarity for a basic Ohm's law question, please?  (Unless, that is, the community's opinion has changed in the last ten years and they're now accepted as on topic.)

I've drafted my question, and can add it here if needed but basically (pun intended) I don't understand why an increase in amps caused by decrease in resistance doesn't have "shocking" result.

Thanks

Comment: *"Basic"* questions have never been declared off-topic - we don't have a close reason for that. What gave you the impression your question would be off-topic here? Note that the meta post you linked is just a *discussion* from ten years ago, there is no actual *policy* against "basic" questions made there.

Comment: Consider also raising your physics and/or policy questions in [chat].

Comment: I'm not sure that there's been a "change" in opinion because there were many people in that 10Y old Q&A indicating the basic questions *are* on topic. I'd say go ahead and post it.

Comment: Re *"an increase in amps"*: I think you mean *"an increase in [current](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current)"*

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you for your contribution and taking time to comment.  It appears I misread the tone / had difficulty parsing that old post, probably as English isn't my first (technically neither my second) language.

Comment: @KyleKanos Much appreciated, thanks for taking time to comment. I'm still developing the question from a thought experiment but I hope to either post it on your main site if I can get it to work; if it doesn't I'll give a brief update here in due course

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Thanks, not being a scientist means I have a limited scientific vocabulary.

Comment: @rob Yes, that's something for me to bear in mind, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by ACuriousMind in [this comment](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14492/site-recommendation-basic-question-concerning-ohms-law#comment55106_14492) and by Kyle Kanos in [this comment](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14492/site-recommendation-basic-question-concerning-ohms-law#comment55108_14492) the recommended site for asking your question may very well be Physics.SE. If you use the tag [ohms-law](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ohms-law), the tag will automatically be converted to [tag:electrical-resistance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electrical-resistance?tab=Newest) which has 2646 questions so far.

There's also [514 questions with the "ohms-law" tag at Electrical Engineering SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ohms-law). They actually have a tag for ohms-law that won't get converted into a more general tag like electrical-resistance.

The Engineering.SE also has [a few tags related to electronics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzTGP.png).

If you ask the question on one of the sites (e.g. Physics.SE) and it turns out to be more appropriate for a different site (e.g. if it's very engineering-related and much more likely to get an answer at ElectricalEngineering.SE), questions can be migrated between the sites as long as the migrations happens within 60 days of the question first being posted. There is actually a close reason on Physics.SE that is described as follows:

> "This question appears to be about engineering, which is the application of scientific knowledge to construct a solution to solve a specific problem. As such, it is off topic for this site, which deals with the science, whether theoretical or experimental, of how the natural world works."

***You probably have enough site suggestions now***, but I'll briefly mention another site that might be of interest, which is [Matter Modeling SE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/) since the policy there is essentially that if someone wants to answer the question, then it's on-topic. A question will almost always only be considered for closure if it can't be answered by anyone for a while (e.g. "needs details for clarity") or if it's a VLQ (***v***ery ***l***ow ***q***uality in the typing/formatting) or if it's a duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: A number of comments deleted. Be kind, folks.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution and taking time to answer.  While researching the detail to develop my thought experiment in to a viable question TIL about *p* resistivity, that R = *p*L/A, and that copper has one of the [lowest *p* values at 1.70](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/elecon.html#c1) - all this means I have more (non-home)work to do.  I shall review your excellent recommendations and return in due course. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Well... you have no current posts so I presume you have deleted a bunch of closed questions so it's difficult to understand what kind of questions you are asking or why they were closed.

I suspect that your are just asking basic homework questions, and those will always be closed.  Before you post again:

1. Have you made a search of the site to look at questions similar to yours?
2. How does your question differ from previous ones?  Can you highlight the differences so your question is not closed as a duplicate?
3. Are you asking for just a calculation or is there something about the physics of Ohm's law you do not understand?

Remember this is not a site for homework help: the goal is not to help you solve a problem, but to help you *understand* a problem.  It's ok to ask basic Ohm's law questions, but it's difficult at this point not to duplicate another question on Ohm's law unless you can highlight the way in which your new question is different from any one of the old questions.

Comment: Well... your presumptions and suspicions about me are not correct. I haven't asked any questions on PhysicsSE - in bunches or otherwise - and I'm not entirely sure how you arrived at that mistaken conclusion. By seeking a site as "I don't understand" something I thought it would be clear my goal was to gain understanding.  Similarly, by including "not homework" I assumed users would see I was not talking about homework: evidently I was mistaken on both counts and I apologise for misleading you in this way. Although I do occasionally work from home, I haven't done homework since getting my PhD.

Comment: Then I’m happy to stand corrected.  The answer holds: there are plenty of questions on Ohm’s law on this site.  Whether or not they are suitable is a other issue.